# how to pass string array between classes in java

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, csv, neo4j

I'm trying to batch load a csv into neo4j and am having trouble passing the string array from the csv loader class into the database creator class. I'm getting errors both in the csvloader (return type for method is missing & syntax error) with the return statement. In NodeLoader CellInput cannot be resolved when I try to call the method. I think I've been staring at this too long.

this is my .csv reader:

```
package com.Neo4J;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CsvLoader {

public CellInput(String[] args){

    String fileName = "data.csv";
    File file = new File(fileName);
    try {
        Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(file);
        inputStream.next(); //ignore first line
        while (inputStream.hasNext()){
            String data = inputStream.next();
            String[] value = data.split(",");
            return String[] value;

        }
        inputStream.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

and this is the database creator:

```
package com.Neo4J;

import org.neo4j.graphdb.Direction;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Node;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Relationship;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.RelationshipType;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;

public class nodeLoader {

// This is the path for Neo4J
private static final String Neo4J_DBPath = "/Program Files (x86)/neo4j-community-1.9.3";

Node one;
Node two;
Node three;
Node four;
Node five;
Node six;
Node seven;

Relationship relation;
GraphDatabaseService graphDataService;

// list of relationships first knows second
private static enum RelTypes implements RelationshipType {
    CONNECTS
}

public static void main(String[] values) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    nodeLoader nodes = new nodeLoader();
    nodes.createDatabase(values);
    nodes.removeData();
    nodes.shutDown();

}

void createDatabase(String[] values) {
    // GraphDatabaseService
    graphDataService = new GraphDatabaseFactory()
            .newEmbeddedDatabase(Neo4J_DBPath);

    // Begin Transaction
    Transaction transaction = graphDataService.beginTx();
    CsvLoader Loader= new CsvLoader();

    try {
        // Create Node & set properties
        one = graphDataService.createNode();
        one.setProperty("Source IP", Loader.CellInput[0]);
        two = graphDataService.createNode();
        two.setProperty("Target Port", Loader.CellInput[1]);
        three = graphDataService.createNode();
        three.setProperty("Protocol", Loader.CellInput[2]);
        four = graphDataService.createNode();
        four.setProperty("Reports", Loader.CellInput[3]);
        five = graphDataService.createNode();
        five.setProperty("Targets", Loader.CellInput[4]);
        six = graphDataService.createNode();
        six.setProperty("First Seen", Loader.CellInput[5]);
        seven = graphDataService.createNode();
        seven.setProperty("Last Seen", Loader.CellInput[6]);

        // Relationship
        relation = one.createRelationshipTo(two, RelTypes.CONNECTS);
        relation = two.createRelationshipTo(three, RelTypes.CONNECTS);
        relation = three.createRelationshipTo(four, RelTypes.CONNECTS);
        relation = four.createRelationshipTo(five, RelTypes.CONNECTS);
        relation = five.createRelationshipTo(six, RelTypes.CONNECTS);
        relation = six.createRelationshipTo(seven, RelTypes.CONNECTS);
        relation = seven.createRelationshipTo(one, RelTypes.CONNECTS);

        relation.setProperty("relationship-type", "CONNECTS");
        System.out.println(one.getProperty("Source IP").toString()
                + relation.getProperty("relationship-type").toString()
                + two.getProperty("Target Port").toString()
                + three.getProperty("Protocol").toString()
                + four.getProperty("Reports").toString()
                + five.getProperty("Targets").toString()
                + six.getProperty("First Seen").toString()
                + seven.getProperty("Last Seen").toString());

        // Success Transaction
        transaction.success();
    } finally {
        // finish the transaction
        transaction.finish();
    }
}

void removeData() {
    Transaction transaction = graphDataService.beginTx();
    try {
        // delete
        one.getSingleRelationship(RelTypes.CONNECTS, Direction.OUTGOING).delete();
        System.out.println("Nodes are removed");

        // delete nodes
        one.delete();
        two.delete();
        three.delete();
        four.delete();
        five.delete();
        six.delete();
        seven.delete();

        transaction.success();
    } finally {
        // finish the transaction
        transaction.finish();

    }
}

void shutDown() {
    // shut down graphDataService
    graphDataService.shutdown();
    System.out.println("Neo4J database is shut down");
}

}
```

Comment: I think you should become familiar with the concept of [arrays themselves](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) first...

Comment: Must be `return value` at least.

Comment: This code cannot compile.

Comment: `public CellInput(String[] args)` neither has a return type nor is it a constructor

Comment: @anubhava that's the OP's complaint.  See the mention of "return type missing and syntax error"?

Answer (score 2):

Some but not all of your problems are stated in the errors you're getting:

1) The `CellInput` method lacks a return type.  I assume from the code that you want to return a `String[]`, in which case the method signature would be:

```
public String[] CellInput(String[] args){
```

2) The `return` statement in the same method is misformed.  `value` already is a String[], so all you ahve to do is

```
return value;
```

3) You're returning from inside the `while` loop, so you'll only get one row. Is that intentional?

4) You need a return statement outside the try/catch: the compiler will rightly notice that if any of the statements inside the try/catch throw an exception, you won't reach the return.

That should be enough to help you get moving forward.